# How to get a value of specific element in json file? (Amazon API)

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services

I am using amazon product api, I'm searching for an item using ASIN number:

```
amazon = require('amazon-product-api');

var client = amazon.createClient({
  awsId: "*",
  awsSecret: "*",
  awsTag: "Tag"

});

client.itemLookup({
  idType: 'ASIN',
  itemId: 'B00WA6ZL8S',
responseGroup :'Variations'
}).then(function(results) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The result is a long JSON file with more than 40000 line of code, here is some of it :

```
[{
"ASIN": ["B00WA6ZL8S"],
"ParentASIN": ["B00WA6ZL8S"],
"VariationSummary": [{ 
    "LowestPrice": [{
     "Amount": ["9200"],"CurrencyCode": ["USD"], "FormattedPrice": ["$92.00"]
    }],
    "HighestPrice": [{
        "Amount": ["13995"],
        "CurrencyCode": ["USD"],
        "FormattedPrice": ["$139.95"]
    }]
}],
"Variations": [{
    "TotalVariations": ["48"],
    "TotalVariationPages": ["1"],
    "VariationDimensions": [{
        "VariationDimension": ["Size", "Color"]
    }],
    "Item": [{
        "ASIN": ["B00RHLICFA"],
        "ParentASIN": ["B00WA6ZL8S"],
        "SmallImage": [{
            "URL": ["http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41z-SPDeICL._SL75_.jpg"],
            "Height": [{
                "_": "35",
                "$": {
                    "Units": "pixels"
                }
            }],
            "Width": [{
                "_": "75",
                "$": {
                    "Units": "pixels"
                }
            }]
        }],
```

How do I get the value of Height or Width ... etc ? And what is the point of the square brackets in "VariationSummary": [{ or "Variations": [{ ?? I mean they are not arrays of objects! .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results[0].Variations[0].Item[0].SmallImage[0].Height[0]._

Sometimes objects are better organized inside an array. You can use array functions like push or pop to organize a large group of objects easier.

Edit, I forgot SmallImage[0] and item[0], corrected answer.

Comment: Not working, it gives me an error : [TypeError: Cannot read property 'Height' of undefined]

Comment: I fixed mistake, try now .SmallImage[0] contains height.

Comment: Try now, made some changes....the issue is accessing the objects within the array... Its a syntax issue...

Comment: This has worked : 

 results[0].Variations[0].Item[0].SmallImage[0].Height[0]._
      Edit your answer so I can give you a vote up.